# Rewrite variables using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

i want to rewrite my variable

```
../detail.php?id=910&type=car
../book.php?id=910&type=car
```

to

```
../detail/car/910
../book/car/910
```

but i don't know how to code it, please give me the code and the explanation. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL rewriting with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Answer (score 2):

Just go to `.htaccess` file make sure your `RewriteEngine on` then write following "RewriteRule" for your URLs:

```
RewriteRule ^detail/(.*)/(.*)$ detail.php?type=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^book/(.*)/(.*)$ book.php?type=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]
```

If yet your rewrite rule not works then add following lines before your rewrite rule

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On
```

**Explanation of above rule:**

`RewriteRule` - Tells Apache that this like refers to a single `RewriteRule`.

`^detail/(.*)/(.*)$ or ^book/(.*)/(.*)$` - **The *pattern***. The server will check the URL of every request to the site to see if this pattern matches. If it does, then Apache will swap the URL of the request for the *substitution* section that follows.

`detail.php?type=$1&id=$2 or book.php?type=$1&id=$2` - **The *substitution***. If the pattern above matches the request, Apache uses this URL instead of the requested URL.

`[NC,L]` - ***Flags***, that tell Apache how to apply the rule. In this case, we're using two flags. `NC`, tells Apache that this rule should be case-insensitive, and `L` tells Apache not to process any more rules if this one is used.